# Selecting an item from a dropdown menu using Python/Selenium

Tags: python, forms, selenium, drop-down-menu

I am trying to fill out a form for states where I would select one at the bottom Oregon. From https://www.adidas.com/us/delivery-start. 
New to coding thank you!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


state = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_delivery"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/fieldset/div/div[1]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div/a/span')
stateselect = state.select_by_visible_test("Oregon")
```

This is the error I am getting

`AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'select_by_visible_test'.`

And with

```
state = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_delivery"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/fieldset/div/div[1]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div/a/span')
stateselect = state.send_keys("Oregon")
```

I get the following :

`error:WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element`

Please help me understand the error for both cases to further my understanding. And point me in the right direction.

Comment: The best way to help you is to help you help yourself. What have you done to try to solve your problem? Lots of other people have encountered the "cannot focus element" error. Have you tried any of the things that worked for them?

Comment: See also: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/2258/24544

Answer (score 1):

When you're copying code always double-check you've copied it correctly.

`select_by_visible_test` should be `select_by_visible_text`

But that won't work because you're not using the select class. Before using `stateselect` you need:

```
stateselect = Select(state)
```

And then you can do:

```
stateselect.select_by_visible_text("Oregon")
```

You should also check the official documentation. In this case, the documentation for the [python selenium api for WebElement](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) and [Select](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select). You can almost always find the documentation by searching for, e.g., "[python selenium select](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+selenium+select)"